# Does $|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-1}$,$|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-1}$ means $f∈C^1(T)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to proof when $|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-1}$,$|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-1}$, ($|a_0\;|≤C$) Fourier series is converged.
I know when $f∈C^1(T)$,Fourier series is converged. but I stuck on the proof of $f∈C^1(T)$ (which means f(x) Differentiable)
I doubt conditions are not enough, maybe it also needs $|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-2}$,$|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-2}$  or a bigger number on the Exponent, then what the number will be?

Comment: The cosine series $\sum \frac 1 n \cos (nx)$ is divergent at $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What does that mean?

Comment: Taking $a_n=0$ and $b_n=\frac 1 n$ we see that the FS need not converge under the given conditions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there any k, that for 1,2,...k,$|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$,$|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$ makes  $f∈C^1(T)$?

Comment: Surely. $k=3$ is more than enough.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you tell me why k = 3?